# Can I simplify these JavaScript ternary operator? `variableA ? variableB : false` to `variableA && variableB`

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have two unknown variables declared somewhere in the top file called `variableA` and `variableB`.

Somewhere in the program, I've encountered these ternary operators

```js
const result = variableA ? variableB : false;
```

I would like my code to be cleaner, but I'm not sure if I can refactor top code to below

```js
const result = variableA && variableB;
```

Are these two lines identical?

---

There is also another case looks like this:

Somewhere in the program:

```js
const result = (variableA && !variableB) || !variableA;
```

Can I simplify the above code below?

```js
const result = variableA && !variableB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these two lines identical?

If `variableA`, if falsey, will always be `false`, yes, they're identical, otherwise, they won't be:

```js
const variableA = 0;
console.log(
  variableA ? variableB : false,
  variableA && variableB
);
```

> Somewhere in the programe:

Those aren't identical either, because `(variableA && !variableB) || !variableA,` will be `true` if `variableA` is true, but `variableB` is not - but `variableA && !variableB` requires `variableA` to be falsey.

```js
const variableA = 0;
console.log(
  (variableA && !variableB) || !variableA,
  variableA && !variableB
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `a` and `b` in these definitions

```
var a = variableA ? variableB : false;
var b = variableA && variableB;
```

is that `a` will be *either* `false` (if `variableA` is falsy) or `variableB` (if `variableB` is truthy`), whereas`b`will be either`variableA`or`variableB`.

Now if `variableA` and `variableB` are already either `true` or `false`, then there's no difference.

And if you use them in a position where only the truthiness of the values matters (for example in an `if`), then there's also no difference.

If you **always** want to have either `true` or `false` as the result (no matter the specific values of `variableA` and `variableB`) then a double negation `!!` will get you there:

```
var c = !!(variableA && variableB);
```

Comment: I dont get the difference between  variableA && variable and !!(variableA && variable) those are the same

Comment: @Eugene: no. If the values are `true` and `"foobar"` respectively, then one of them will result in `"foobar"` and the other will result in `true`. They are only the same if both variables already hold `boolean` values.